# Listening to JS CustomEvent in Dart

Tags: dart, dart-html, dart-js-interop

I know that my question is not new, but all solutions I've found here and in the Internet are not working :( Or, I'm doing something completely wrong.

I need to create a communication between Dart and JS, and I would love to use events, as the idea seems to be neat  and simple.

So, I tried this tutorial: https://dart.academy/easy-dart-js-interopt/

My JS code:

```
var customEvent = new CustomEvent("fromJavascriptToDart");
window.onload = document.dispatchEvent(customEvent);
document.addEventListener("fromJavascriptToDart", test, false);
function test() {
    console.log("Listening");
}
```

The event is dispatched, as I see Listening in console log.

But when it comes to dart, nothing is working.

I've tried the following methods and everything failed:

```
document.on['fromJavascriptToDart'].listen((CustomEvent event) {
                    print("HEY! I'M LISTENING!");
                });
window.on["fromJavascriptToDart"].listen((e) => print( "HEY! I'M LISTENING!"));
window.on['foo'].add((e) => print(e.detail)); //This is not working, as there is no add method in Stream Event anymore
@Listen('fromJavascriptToDart')
    void eventTest(){
        print("HEY! I'M LISTENING!");
    }
```

Any help is mostly appreciated.

Comment: `document.on['fromJavascriptToDart'].listen((CustomEvent event) {
                    print("HEY! I'M LISTENING!");
                });` is working fine. https://dartpad.dartlang.org/9cc2ecbe7a0b6479c56de882566982c9 
The last example looks like Polymer.

Comment: Actually, I do not see any logs from dart. I don't see "HEY! I'M LISTENING!" Is it possible, that I'm listening it from the wrong place? I have an App class that is started with the App initialisation. And there I've added those listeners.

Comment: Oh, stop. Everything is working now. Your answer worked liked magic trigger, and I see lots of "HEY! I'M LISTENING!" in console. Though, I was struggling for an couple of hours with that. Would you mind add this as an answer, so I can mark is as a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**DartPad example**](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/9cc2ecbe7a0b6479c56de882566982c9)

```
document.on['fromJavascriptToDart'].listen((CustomEvent event) {
  print("HEY! I'M LISTENING!");
});
```

Works fine.

- `@Listen()` is Polymer specific
- `add` doesn't exist (`listen` as show above should be used)
- the event doesn't seem to reach `window`, but I'm sure this will behave the same in pure JS.