# How do I listen custom js window events in dart 2.15 / flutter 2.8

Tags: javascript, html, flutter, dart, events

I'm using flutter for web. I want to process custom event in my flutter javascript code. I open popup window from flutter:

```
import 'dart:js' as js;
js.context.callMethod('open', ['http://localhost:8083/popup-page.html?params', 'loginWindow', 'width=600,height=600,left=600,top=200']);
```

`popup-page.html` is part of my flutter web application. During its lifecycle `popup-page.html` is reloaded several times so I can't just assign my callback function to some specific dom.window object. So in `popup-page.html` I have the following javascript to call back my flutter code when needed:

```
opener.parent.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('myCallback', {detail: callbackDetailsObj}));
```

Now I want to get and process callbackDetailsObj in my flutter app.

My initial idea was to use `window.addEventListener('myCallback', callback)` or `window.on['myCallback'].listen(callback)` from `dart:html` package. In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13902121/5260478) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43640095/5260478) examples people are just using `CustomEvent` as callback function arg and casting event.detail to custom dart class. But for me that doesn't work. First - in my callback I get instance of `JavaScriptObject` for event arg. That JavaScriptObject can't be cast to either `CustomEvent` or event `Event` (despite the fact `EventListener` arg is `typedef EventListener(Event event)`). So I was not able to cast or convert `JavaScriptObject` to anything useful (including `JsObject` from `dart:js` package) and also was not able to get any fields of that object - e.g. type, target, details.

So in order to create working solution I used `context.callMethod` + `allowInterop`:

```
import 'dart:js' as js;
  void addListener() {
    var callbackPopupJs = js.allowInterop(callbackPopup);
    js.JsObject options = js.JsObject.jsify({'once': true});
    js.context.callMethod('addEventListener', ['myCallback', callbackPopupJs, options]);
  }

  void callbackPopup(js.JsObject ev) {
    developer.log('Browser Callback');
    developer.log('Event type: ${ev['type']}, runtime: ${ev.runtimeType}, target: ${ev['target']}');
    developer.log('Detail : ${ev['detail']}');
  }
```

And now I'm able to get `CustomEvent.detail`. But I'm not if this method is optimal and it's not possible to use [window.addEventListener()](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.15.0/dart-html/EventTarget/addEventListener.html) and [CustomEvent](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.14.4/dart-html/CustomEvent-class.html) to process window callbacks.